# Is there an operator that works like Scan but let's me return an IObservable<TResult> instead of IObservable<TSource>?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In this made up example purely for practice, here is what I want to return:

If two students join a school within a specified period of time, say, 2 seconds, then I want a data structure returning both the students, the school they joined and the time interval between their joining.

I have been thinking along these lines:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObserveStudentsJoiningWithin(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }

    static void ObserveStudentsJoiningWithin(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var school = new School("School 1");

        var admissionObservable =
            Observable.FromEventPattern<StudentAdmittedEventArgs>(school, "StudentAdmitted");

        var observable = admissionObservable.TimeInterval()
            .Scan((current, next) =>
            {
                if (next.Interval - current.Interval <= timeSpan)
                {
                    // But this won't work for me because
                    // this requires me to return a TSource
                    // and not a TResult
                }
            });

        var subscription = observable.Subscribe(TimeIntervalValueHandler);

        school.FillWithStudentsAsync(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        school.FillWithStudentsAsync(8, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program");
        Console.ReadKey();
        subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And here is the domain:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SchoolManagementSystem
{
    public class Student
    {
        private static int _studentNumber; 

        public Student(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static Student CreateRandom()
        {
            var name = string.Format($"Student {++_studentNumber}");

            return new Student(name);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    public class School: IEnumerable<Student>
    {
        private List<Student> _students;

        public event StudentAdmitted StudentAdmitted;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public School(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            _students = new List<Student>();
        }

        public void AdmitStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (!_students.Contains(student))
            {
                _students.Add(student);

                OnStudentAdmitted(this, student);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnStudentAdmitted(School school, Student student)
        {
            var args = new StudentAdmittedEventArgs(school, student);

            StudentAdmitted?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        public IEnumerator<Student> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _students.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }


    public delegate void StudentAdmitted(object sender, StudentAdmittedEventArgs args);

    public class StudentAdmittedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public StudentAdmittedEventArgs(School school, Student student): base()
        {
            School = school;
            Student = student;
        }

        public School School { get; protected set; }
        public Student Student { get; protected set;  }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public async static void FillWithStudentsAsync(this School school, int howMany, TimeSpan gapBetweenEachAdmission)
        {
            if (school == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("school");

            if (howMany < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("howMany");

            if (howMany == 1)
            {
                school.AdmitStudent(Student.CreateRandom());
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(gapBetweenEachAdmission);

                school.AdmitStudent(Student.CreateRandom());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `Scan` operator allows me to only return an observable of the same `TSource`. `Select` also won't work here because I cannot *look ahead* (something that I can do with `Scan`) and project the current item along with the next one, even though `Select` allows me to transform `TSource` into `TResult`.

I am looking for something in between.

Comment: [`Observable.Scan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212007.aspx) does let you return the accumulator type.

Comment: My bad. You're right. If you put that down as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a pairwise comparison (*original* - project the current item along with the next one) you can use a [Buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212130(v=vs.103).aspx) method to build a sequence with pairs.
2. In order to find out an interval between students joinings using the [Timestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211605(v=vs.103).aspx) instead of [TimeInterval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff708176(v=vs.110).aspx) method could be more useful because of the following line `next.Interval - current.Interval <= timeSpan`. What you really want is something like `pair[1].Timestamp - pair[0].Timestamp <= timeSpan`

Following results in 4 pairs (Student 11, Student 12), (Student 13, Student 14), (Student 15, Student 16), (Student 17, Student 18):

```
var admissionObservable = Observable
        .FromEventPattern<StudentAdmittedEventArgs>(school, "StudentAdmitted")
        .Timestamp()
        .Buffer(2)
        .Where(pair => pair[1].Timestamp - pair[0].Timestamp <= timeSpan)
        .Select(pair => new JoiningData
        {
            Students = Tuple.Create(pair[0].Value.EventArgs.Student, pair[1].Value.EventArgs.Student),
            School = pair[0].Value.EventArgs.School,
            Interval = pair[1].Timestamp - pair[0].Timestamp
        });
```

3. As @Enigmativity mentioned it would be better to compare each element with the next one. So for that purpose we can use a [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.zip(v=vs.103).aspx) method:

Following results in 8 pairs (Student 10, Student 11) (Student 11, Student 12), (Student 12, Student 13), (Student 13, Student 14), (Student 14, Student 15), (Student 15, Student 16), (Student 16, Student 17), (Student 17, Student 18):

```
var admissionObservable = Observable
     .FromEventPattern<StudentAdmittedEventArgs>(school, "StudentAdmitted")
     .Timestamp();        

admissionObservable
    .Zip(admissionObservable.Skip(1), (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a,b))        
    .Where(pair => pair.Item2.Timestamp - pair.Item1.Timestamp <= timeSpan)        
    .Select(pair => new JoiningData
    {
        Students = Tuple.Create(pair.Item1.Value.EventArgs.Student, pair.Item2.Value.EventArgs.Student),
        School = pair.Item1.Value.EventArgs.School,
        Interval = pair.Item2.Timestamp - pair.Item1.Timestamp
    });
```

Comment: Very beautiful indeed. Thank you much much. I have implemented it using `Scan` and will post it soon. You're right about the `if` condition. I had to change it as it was erroneous anyway. But this is a very interesting method. Because before completing my solution using `Scan`, I was actually wondering if I should have recorded the `DateTime` a student was admitted inside the `Admitted` event and sent that information along with the `EventArgs`. Turns out I could do without that with just `Scan` but this is very interesting.

Comment: This query groups the students into pairs like `(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)` etc, but doesn't check `1 & 2` , `3 & 4` etc.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Yes, otherwise one element would be stored twice if appropriate, e.g "Student 11" in (Student 10, Student 11) and (Student 11, Student 12). Added a solution for this approach.

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy - Which is what is needed I thought. If Student 1 joined and within two seconds Student 2 joined then you'd want that pair returned. What also isn't clear is that if 1, 2 & 3 all joined within three seconds would the pair of 1 & 3 also need to be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this and see if it gives you what you want?

```
IObservable<EventPattern<StudentAdmittedEventArgs>[]> observable =
    admissionObservable
        .Publish(pxs =>
            pxs
                .Window(pxs, x => Observable.Timer(timeSpan))
                .Select(ys => ys.Take(2)))
        .SelectMany(ys => ys.ToArray())
        .Where(ys => ys.Skip(1).Any());
```

Comment: Because the window closing boundary is time-based, won't this return *all students who joined within 2 seconds* and then take the second one of that lot / window?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - Yes, that's what the `.Take(2)` does - it gets only the first pair in the window. It should produce the correct results. I did test it myself before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
static void ObserveStudentsJoiningWithin(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var school = new School("School 1");

    var admissionObservable =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<StudentAdmittedEventArgs>(school, "StudentAdmitted");

    var observable = admissionObservable.TimeInterval()
        .Scan<TimeInterval<EventPattern<StudentAdmittedEventArgs>>, StudentPair>(null, (previousPair, current) =>
        {
            Debug.Print(string.Format($"Student joined after {current.Interval.TotalSeconds} seconds, timeSpan = {timeSpan.TotalSeconds} seconds"));

            var pair = new StudentPair();

            if (previousPair == null)
            {
                pair.FirstStudent = null;
                pair.SecondStudent = current.Value.EventArgs.Student;
                pair.IntervalBetweenJoining = current.Interval;
                pair.School = current.Value.EventArgs.School;

                return pair;
            }

            if (current.Interval <= timeSpan)
            {
                pair.FirstStudent = previousPair.SecondStudent;
                pair.SecondStudent = current.Value.EventArgs.Student;
                pair.IntervalBetweenJoining = current.Interval;
                pair.School = current.Value.EventArgs.School;

                return pair;
            }
            else
            {
                return default(StudentPair);
            }
        })
        .Where(p => (p != default(StudentPair)) && (p.FirstStudent != null));

    var subscription = observable.Subscribe(StudentPairValueHandler);

    school.FillWithStudents(4, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    school.FillWithStudents(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    school.FillWithStudents(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    school.FillWithStudents(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    school.FillWithStudents(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6));

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program");
    Console.ReadKey();
    subscription.Dispose();
}

static void StudentPairValueHandler(StudentPair pair)
{
    if (pair != null && pair.FirstStudent != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.SecondStudent.Name} joined {pair.School.Name} {Math.Round(pair.IntervalBetweenJoining.TotalSeconds, 2)} seconds after {pair.FirstStudent.Name}.");
    }
}

...

public class StudentPair
{
    public Student FirstStudent;
    public Student SecondStudent;
    public School School;
    public TimeSpan IntervalBetweenJoining;
}


public static class Extensions
{
    public static void FillWithStudents(this School school, int howMany)
    {
        FillWithStudents(school, howMany, TimeSpan.Zero);
    }

    public static void FillWithStudents(this School school, int howMany, TimeSpan gapBetweenEachAdmission)
    {
        if (school == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("school");

        if (howMany < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("howMany");

        if (howMany == 1)
        {
            school.AdmitStudent(Student.CreateRandom());
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep((int)gapBetweenEachAdmission.TotalMilliseconds);

            school.AdmitStudent(Student.CreateRandom());
        }
    }

    public async static void FillWithStudentsAsync(this School school, int howMany, TimeSpan gapBetweenEachAdmission)
    {
        if (school == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("school");

        if (howMany < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("howMany");

        if (howMany == 1)
        {
            school.AdmitStudent(Student.CreateRandom());
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(gapBetweenEachAdmission);

            school.AdmitStudent(Student.CreateRandom());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you are doing here, but it is not very idiomatic Rx. See the other answers for "better" designs.

Comment: @LeeCampbell Thank you. I realize that and am slowly improving my Rx way of thinking. On another note, I must tell you that I find your book as a great learning resource. It is one of the best books I have read in a long time. It is well-written and just beautiful overall. I learn so much from reading it. I haven't read it fully yet because I re-read portions of it again and again and practice things slowly many times.